# How to root galaxy s9+

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-9

Is there any guide or can somebody tell me how to root my s9+. Sorry for incompetence, I'm new to this)

Answer (score 0):

Rooting will trip knox and void your warranty, before rooting read the pros & cons of doing so, and then decide if it is worth it.

You can follow this guide

https://www.theandroidsoul.com/samsung-galaxy-s9-root/